# Python SQL query on a SQL Server Database is running extremely slow, using both cursor.execute() and read_sql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have read access to a SQL Server and I reference 2 separate databases on that server.  I need to do a query on a set of filtered id's, ranging from 500 - 10,000 id's depending on the day received as an excel spread sheet and loaded into python via pandas DataFrame

Note, I don't have access to this database via SSMS so python is my only way in.
The query is very simple,

```
query = "SELECT case.id as m, case.owner as o FROM case WHERE case.id = ? "
```

I put this through a loop and append the data through a list ref

```
for i in case['id']:
    ref.append(cursor.execute(query, i).fetchone()
```

or append to a dataframe

```
for i in case['id']:
    df.append(pd.read_sql_query(query, con, params = [i]))
```

Fairly straightforward, however it is agonizingly slow.  Am I doing something wrong here?

I used to do this with Visual Basic and, using arrays and loops, was blindingly fast.

Any advice on this would be duly appreciated.

Comment: Can you pass the ids in chunks to your query as an `IN` query. Or just in one massive query to begin with

Comment: The reason i cant use an ```IN``` query is because i also have to use those same ID's to do a far more complicated query with several joins.  This caused everything to crash on my end so i was left looping through each ID.  The query i am posting here I minimized to two columns to see why the query was so slow, but even with 2 columns queried it was running very slow.

Comment: Wouldn't the id be returned by the query?

Comment: _"even with 2 columns queried it was running very slow."_ yes, latency is a killer for large numbers of small-sized queries. Another reason to avoid RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row). If you can't use `IN` can you restructure it as a `select ID, ... from (values ...) Src(ID) ...` and join on that? At least then your `ID` values can be returned with the other join data.

Comment: How about loading the ID values in to a table variable? `DECLARE @ids TABLE (id int PRIMARY KEY);`

Comment: So, what happened was is I messed up.  I did not format my python code to accept a tuple of id's into the IN query.  Once I found out how to do that, the IN query works for the 500 - 10000 ids needed.